# How can I exclude data tails from factoring into size of data point in ggplot2 (using scale_size or something similar)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I'm looking to include a size component to geom_point that adjusts based on the variable selected. However, I would like to exclude the higher ends of the variable's range from factoring into the size of the point. In a range of values from 0-600, I would like the show only values exceeding 50 (with the smallest size starting at 50), and then I'd like the maximum point size to be reached at 300, with the points closer to 600 being the same size as the point with a value of 300. Is there any way to do this? My goal is to show more of the variance between 50-300, as the difference between 300 and 600 in my data set isn't that important.

Somewhat separately, I'm looking to integrate this feature into a shiny app, where the data will be subsetted by the row inputs the user selects (ID variable in example). Certain subsets will only have size variable data between 50-150, whereas some will have data between 150-600. Hoping for a solution that lends itself to data point size comparability across subsets. Using default settings, each ID subset will have similar sized points, but with significantly different value ranges. I'd like all the data points for the "A" plot to be smaller than that of "B" and "C" (when plotting "A" by itself, no facet_wrap), and I'd like all the values over 300 to be the same size. Tried playing with `limits`, `breaks`, `n.breaks`, etc., to no avail.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                        "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
                        "C", "C", "C","C", "C", "C"),
                 x_axis = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
                            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
                            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                 y_axis = c(.5, .6, .8, .4, .9, .8,
                            .3, .4, .5, .4, .7, .4,
                            .6, .6, .7, .6, .6, .8),
                 size = c(50, 75, 150, 100, 125, 140,
                          475, 600, 275, 100, 250, 350,
                          125, 180, 210, 155, 100, 200))
```

Comment: (1) *"show only values"* suggests filtering before you plot. (2) Assuming that the 50-300 range is per `ID`, then this might be a lookup or merge/join (e.g., `data.frame(ID=c("A","B"),lo=c(50,200),hi=c(300,500))`), then `filter`, then normalize (divide by this `ID`'s median or max or such), then plot. (3) Integrating into [tag:shiny] has nothing to do with the filtering and visualization with this reduced-range logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector with the values you want and map that to size. Then also filter out the values you want to remove

```
df$point.size = pmin(df$size, 300)
ggplot(df[df$size > 50,], aes(x_axis, y_axis, size=point.size)) +
  geom_point()
```

or just

```
ggplot(df[df$size > 50,], aes(x_axis, y_axis, size = pmin(size, 300))) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Would `pmin(df$size, 300)` be more direct?